# Angular - Occasional: 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Tags: jquery, angular

I know there are similar questions, but this is not quite the same flavor.  Simply because this works nearly every time, and only occasionally fails.

I have the following code in Angular.

-- at the top of the component

> declare var $: any;

-- in component code during **`ngOnInit()`**

```
  const nav = $('header');
```

Here's where it gets odd.  This is my header, executed on every single page.  Getting hit 1,000s of times a day. It works more than 99% of the time.  I started this project in Angular 5, upgraded to 6, upgraded to 7. The whole time, on rare occasions, I get the following error.  Why??

I can never recreate it, nor can I figure out why it happens.  I've been living with it for years, and have no clue.  Any idea how to track this down?   I've tried using JQUERY instead, and it makes no difference.

```
    ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at HeaderComponent.push../src/app/master/controls/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.ngOnInit (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:142368:9)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:55800:19)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:57064:20)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:57026:16)
    at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:57567:5)
    at Object.updateDirectives (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:140269:2632)
    at Object.updateDirectives (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:57355:72)
    at checkAndUpdateView (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:57008:14)
    at callViewAction (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:57249:21)
    at execComponentViewsAction (https://www.example.com/main.02e5859888e52b1dd87a.js:57191:13)
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery with Angular, end of story. There is only pain and misery on that path!

Comment: I agree with @AdrianBrand, There are things you could do in Angular without even having to use JQuery

Comment: I would rather suggest you to help me understand what you are trying to achieve that so that i could assist you an alternate approach of doing it in Angular.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/error-referenceerror-is-not-defined-at-angulardatata

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 
My user has several JQuery controls that they really wanted me to use.   These require an integration of JQuery and Angular.  Such as FlipClock, Odometer, SimpleMaps, FancyBox, and some custom Dropdown and File Upload controls that they found elsewhere that they loved.

If you are suggesting I get rid of JQuery as a fix, I can go back to them and let them know it is causing instability.  They are upset with the instability, and if I can use this as a cause to push to materials, that is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is chance that jQuery might be taking time to load sometimes. How you are loading jquery, Is it from CDN or from node_modules as dependency.

Best practice is to add

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

in angular.json

PS: It is not recommended to use jQuery for this case. If you want to get element reference you can do so by `ViewChild()`

```
<header #myname>
@ViewChild('myname') header;
```

Comment: I apologize for the late response.  I load Jquery from https://code.jquery.com.

Your point of @ViewChild will actually resolve a great many of my Jquery needs.